# Diamond Dust - Reflection and Shimmering

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction, weather

Diamond dust is a natural phenomenon that occurs when ice crystals form closer to Earth and interact with sunlight. Now diamond dust shimmers because of the reflection and refraction of sunlight. I know that the shimmering of light on water is formed due to specular reflection therefore I wanted to know if the same applies to ice crystals.